# How can I convert String[] to int[]?

Tags: java

This may be an obvious question, I don't know, but I could not find any answers anywhere.
So, I have a JTextField which is getting some text and putting it into a string[] but i want it into an int[] instead. Here's a bit of my code, but of course i have errors with that and I need it to convert to int[]. Any ideas of how i can do this?

Also the code i am having trouble with is inside of the button actionevent, just so you find it easily :) Thank you!

```
private void initComponents() {
            // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY
            // //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
            // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Will Baker
            textField9 = new JTextField();
            textField10 = new JTextField();
            label10 = new JLabel();
            label9 = new JLabel();
            button5 = new JButton();

            // ======== this ========
            Container contentPane = getContentPane();
            contentPane.setLayout(null);
            contentPane.add(textField9);
            textField9.setBounds(90, 15, 273,
                    textField9.getPreferredSize().height);
            contentPane.add(textField10);
            textField10.setBounds(90, 40, 273,
                    textField10.getPreferredSize().height);

            // ---- label10 ----
            label10.setText("Loot Name(s):");
            contentPane.add(label10);
            label10.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(20, 40), label10
                    .getPreferredSize()));

            // ---- label9 ----
            label9.setText("NPC Name(s):");
            contentPane.add(label9);
            label9.setBounds(20, 10, 68, 25);

            // ---- button5 ----
            button5.setText("Start!");
            button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    NPC_NAME = textField9.getText().split(",");
                    LOOT_NAMES = textField10.getText().split(",");

                    running = true;
                    gui.dispose();
                }
            });
            contentPane.add(button5);
            button5.setBounds(90, 70, 208, button5.getPreferredSize().height);

            { // compute preferred size
                Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
                for (int i = 0; i < contentPane.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                    Rectangle bounds = contentPane.getComponent(i).getBounds();
                    preferredSize.width = Math.max(bounds.x + bounds.width,
                            preferredSize.width);
                    preferredSize.height = Math.max(bounds.y + bounds.height,
                            preferredSize.height);
                }
                Insets insets = contentPane.getInsets();
                preferredSize.width += insets.right;
                preferredSize.height += insets.bottom;
                contentPane.setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
                contentPane.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
            }
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
            // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization
            // //GEN-END:initComponents
        }

        // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY
        // //GEN-BEGIN:variables
        // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Will Baker
        private JTextField textField9;
        private JTextField textField10;
        private JLabel label10;
        private JLabel label9;
        private JButton button5;
        // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration //GEN-END:variables
    }
```

Comment: By iterating over your `String[]` and calling `Integer.parseInt()` while you populate a `int[]`

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Why post all this irrelevant code? Start by writing a method with the following signature: `int[] stringArrayToIntArray(String[] strings)`. Then implement it. You'll need a loop, and you'll need to find, in the javadoc of java.lang.Integer, how to transform a String to an int. Shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement it by yourself. It should looks like that:

```
public int[] stringsToInts(String[] strings){
    int[] ints = new int[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.lengths; i++){
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
    }
    return ints;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no magical built-in function for that. You will need to implement one yourself.

Just create int[] and iterate through string[] and in every iteration parse the string and save it into the new array matching index, when you finish just return the new int[] array.